# QtWebKit CSS Path

Tags: c++, qt, css-selectors, pyqt5, qtwebkit

Having an `QWebElement`, how to generate the unique CSS path for that element?

The argument for:

```
QWebElement::findFirst(const QString & selectorQuery)
```

(something like "Copy CSS path" in Chrome or "Copy Unique Selector" in Firefox)

Comment: This question is probably no different from any other "how to generate a unique selector" question, even if it might be the first one asked in the context of QtWebKit. A selector is a selector, and an element is an element.

Comment: That question and answer is about JavaScript "onclick event handler", it's not about QtWebKit/C++.

Comment: You know what, you're right. The asker of that question doesn't really want to generate a unique selector after all. Having said that, I'm still not sure we need language-specific versions of "how to generate a unique selector". Maybe I'll write a canonical... when I have the time to actually answer it.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in method in Qt for generating an unique selector. It also doesn't exist in JavaScript. However for JavaScript there are some libraries that do the job. [css-selector-generator](https://github.com/fczbkk/css-selector-generator) and [unique selector](https://github.com/ericclemmons/unique-selector).

Comment: What's your use case? Maybe invoking `QWebElement::evaluateJavaScript` and using `this` for the element is a better way for QtWebKit.